# RAILS 5: ActionController::ParameterMissing - Unable to get RSPEC to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, tdd

I am unsure how to make my test pass as i am new to TDD.

i have the below failing test for `creates a waitinglist email` in my spec displaying:

```
Failure/Error: params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:email)
     
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: waitinglist
```

i am unsure how to get my test to pass when the `waitinglist_params` is stated `params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:email)` in the controller. Where am I going wrong?

waitinglists_controller.rb

```
class WaitinglistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_waitinglist, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]  

  def create
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.create!(waitinglist_params)
    render json: @waitinglist, status: :created
  end

  private
  def set_waitinglist
    @waitinglist = Waitinglist.find(params[:id])
  end

  def waitinglist_params
    params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

i have the spec:

```
RSpec.describe 'Waitinglists API', type: :request do
  let!(:waitinglists) { create_list(:waitinglist, 10) }
  let!(:waitinglist_id) { waitinglists.first.id }


  #CRUD: Create - POST request [create]
  describe 'POST /waitinglists' do
    let(:valid_attributes) { { email: 'john.doe@example.com' } }

    context 'when the request is valid' do
      before { post '/waitinglists', params: valid_attributes }

      it 'creates a waitinglist email' do
        expect(json['email']).to eq('john.doe@example.com')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you try `let(:valid_attributes) { { waitinglist: { email: 'john.doe@example.com' } } }`

Comment: thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your parameters into hash with key `waitinglist` like so:

```rb
params: { waitinglist: { email: 'john.doe@example.com' } }
```